# django website not displaying due to urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

i have a problem with my urls.py file.it keeps saying there is a syntax error on line 16, the one with a login view(accounts/login).have tried to fix it but have failed.what am i doing wrong ?

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.debug import default_urlconf
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
#admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [

  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  url(r'^$', 'article.views.articles', name='home'),
  url(r'^article/', include('article.urls')),
  url(r'^accounts/', include('userprof.urls')),
  url(r'^$', default_urlconf)
  #url(r'^all/$', 'article.views.articles',name='articles'),
  url(r'^accounts/login/$',  'brn.views.login'),
  url(r'^accounts/auth/$',  'brn.views.auth_view'),
  url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'brn.views.logout'),
  url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', 'brn.views.loggedin'),
  url(r'^accounts/invalid/$', 'brn.views.invalid_login'),
  url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'brn.views.register_user'),
  url(r'^accounts/register_success/$', 'brn.views.register_success'),

  # url(r'^search/',SearchView(load_all = False)),
  #url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG: urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',    {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

Comment: you are missing a comma at the end of the line 15

Answer (score 2):

There's a missing comma at line 15

```
 url(r'^$', default_urlconf)
```

it should be

```
 url(r'^$', default_urlconf),
 #url(r'^all/$', 'article.views.articles',name='articles'),
 url(r'^accounts/login/$',  'brn.views.login'),
```